# JGoodies HashMap

Tags: java, binding, hashmap, jgoodies

I'm trying to build a chart program using presentation model. Using JGoodies for data binding was relatively easy for simple types like strings or numbers. But I can't figure out how to use it on a hashmap.

I'll try to explain how the chart works and what my problem is:

A chart consists of DataSeries, a DataSeries consists of DataPoints. I want to have a data model and to be able to use different views on the same model (e.g. bar chart, pie chart,...). Each of them consists of three classes.
For example:
DataPointModel: holds the data model (value, label, category)
DataPointViewModel: extends JGoodies PresentationModel. wraps around DataPointModel and holds view properties like font and color.
DataPoint: abstract class, extends JComponent. Different Views must subclass and implement their own ui.

Binding and creating the data model was easy, but i don't know how to bind my data series model.

```
package at.onscreen.chart;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;



public class DataSeriesModel {

 public static String PROPERTY_DATAPOINT = "dataPoint";
 public static String PROPERTY_DATAPOINTS = "dataPoints";
 public static String PROPERTY_LABEL = "label";
 public static String PROPERTY_MAXVALUE = "maxValue";

 /**
  * holds the data points
  */
 private HashMap<String, DataPoint> dataPoints;

 /**
  * the label for the data series
  */
 private String label;

 /**
  * the maximum data point value
  */
 private Double maxValue;

 /**
  * the model supports property change notification
  */
 private PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport;

 /**
  * default constructor
  */
 public DataSeriesModel() {
  this.maxValue = Double.valueOf(0);
  this.dataPoints = new HashMap<String, DataPoint>();
  this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  */
 public DataSeriesModel(String label) {
  this.dataPoints = new HashMap<String, DataPoint>();
  this.maxValue = Double.valueOf(0);
  this.label = label;
  this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - an array of data points
  */
 public DataSeriesModel(String label, DataPoint[] dataPoints) {
  this.dataPoints = new HashMap<String, DataPoint>();
  this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  this.maxValue = Double.valueOf(0);
  this.label = label;
  for (int i = 0; i < dataPoints.length; i++) {
   this.addDataPoint(dataPoints[i]);
  }
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - a collection of data points
  */
 public DataSeriesModel(String label, Collection<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
  this.dataPoints = new HashMap<String, DataPoint>();
  this.propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
  this.maxValue = Double.valueOf(0);
  this.label = label;
  for (Iterator<DataPoint> it = dataPoints.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   this.addDataPoint(it.next());
  }
 }

 /**
  * adds a new data point to the series. if the series contains a data point with same id, it will be replaced by the new one.
  * @param dataPoint - the data point  
  */
 public void addDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
  String category = dataPoint.getCategory();
  DataPoint oldDataPoint = this.getDataPoint(category);
  this.dataPoints.put(category, dataPoint);
  this.setMaxValue(Math.max(this.maxValue, dataPoint.getValue()));
  this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROPERTY_DATAPOINT, oldDataPoint, dataPoint);
 }

 /**
  * returns the data point with given id or null if not found
  * @param uid - the id of the data point
  * @return the data point or null if there is no such point in the table
  */
 public DataPoint getDataPoint(String category) {
  return this.dataPoints.get(category);
 }

 /**
  * removes the data point with given id from the series, if present
  * @param category - the data point to remove
  */
 public void removeDataPoint(String category) {
  DataPoint dataPoint = this.getDataPoint(category);
  this.dataPoints.remove(category);
  if (dataPoint != null) {
   if (dataPoint.getValue() == this.getMaxValue()) {
    Double maxValue = Double.valueOf(0);
    for (Iterator<DataPoint> it = this.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
     DataPoint itDataPoint = it.next();
     maxValue = Math.max(itDataPoint.getValue(), maxValue);
    }
    this.setMaxValue(maxValue);
   }
  }
  this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROPERTY_DATAPOINT, dataPoint, null);
 }

 /**
  * removes all data points from the series
  * @throws PropertyVetoException 
  */
 public void removeAll() {
  this.setMaxValue(Double.valueOf(0));
  this.dataPoints.clear();
  this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROPERTY_DATAPOINTS, this.getDataPoints(), null);
 }

 /**
  * returns the maximum of all data point values
  * @return the maximum of all data points
  */
 public Double getMaxValue() {
  return this.maxValue;
 }

 /**
  * sets the max value
  * @param maxValue - the max value
  */
 protected void setMaxValue(Double maxValue) {
  Double oldMaxValue = this.getMaxValue();
  this.maxValue = maxValue;
  this.propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PROPERTY_MAXVALUE, oldMaxValue, maxValue);
 }

 /**
  * returns true if there is a data point with given category
  * @param category - the data point category
  * @return true if there is a data point with given category, otherwise false
  */
 public boolean contains(String category) {
  return this.dataPoints.containsKey(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns the label for the series
  * @return the label for the series
  */
 public String getLabel() {
  return this.label;
 }

 /**
  * returns an iterator over the data points
  * @return an iterator over the data points
  */
 public Iterator<DataPoint> iterator() {
  return this.dataPoints.values().iterator();
 }

 /**
  * returns a collection of the data points. the collection supports removal, but does not support adding of data points.
  * @return a collection of data points
  */
 public Collection<DataPoint> getDataPoints() {
  return this.dataPoints.values();
 }

 /**
  * returns the number of data points in the series
  * @return the number of data points
  */
 public int getSize() {
  return this.dataPoints.size();
 }

 /**
  * adds a PropertyChangeListener
  * @param listener - the listener
  */
 public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
  this.propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }

 /**
  * removes a PropertyChangeListener
  * @param listener - the listener
  */
 public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
  this.propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
 }
}

    package at.onscreen.chart;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.jgoodies.binding.PresentationModel;

public class DataSeriesViewModel extends PresentationModel<DataSeriesModel> {

 /**
  * default constructor
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel() {
  super(new DataSeriesModel());
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel(String label) {
  super(new DataSeriesModel(label));
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - an array of data points
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel(String label, DataPoint[] dataPoints) {
  super(new DataSeriesModel(label, dataPoints));
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - a collection of data points
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel(String label, Collection<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
  super(new DataSeriesModel(label, dataPoints));
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param model - the data series model
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel(DataSeriesModel model) {
  super(model);
 }

 /**
  * adds a data point to the series
  * @param dataPoint - the data point
  */
 public void addDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
  this.getBean().addDataPoint(dataPoint);
 }

 /**
  * returns true if there is a data point with given category
  * @param category - the data point category
  * @return true if there is a data point with given category, otherwise false
  */
 public boolean contains(String category) {
  return this.getBean().contains(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns the data point with given id or null if not found
  * @param uid - the id of the data point
  * @return the data point or null if there is no such point in the table
  */
 public DataPoint getDataPoint(String category) {
  return this.getBean().getDataPoint(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns a collection of the data points. the collection supports removal, but does not support adding of data points.
  * @return a collection of data points
  */
 public Collection<DataPoint> getDataPoints() {
  return this.getBean().getDataPoints();
 }

 /**
  * returns the label for the series
  * @return the label for the series
  */
 public String getLabel() {
  return this.getBean().getLabel();
 }

 /**
  * sets the max value
  * @param maxValue - the max value
  */
 public Double getMaxValue() {
  return this.getBean().getMaxValue();
 }

 /**
  * returns the number of data points in the series
  * @return the number of data points
  */
 public int getSize() {
  return this.getBean().getSize();
 }

 /**
  * returns an iterator over the data points
  * @return an iterator over the data points
  */
 public Iterator<DataPoint> iterator() {
  return this.getBean().iterator();
 }

 /**
  * removes all data points from the series
  * @throws PropertyVetoException 
  */
 public void removeAll() {
  this.getBean().removeAll();
 }

 /**
  * removes the data point with given id from the series, if present
  * @param category - the data point to remove
  */
 public void removeDataPoint(String category) {
  this.getBean().removeDataPoint(category);
 }
}

    package at.onscreen.chart;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.swing.JComponent;


public abstract class DataSeries extends JComponent implements PropertyChangeListener {

 /**
  * the model
  */
 private DataSeriesViewModel model;

 /**
  * default constructor
  */
 public DataSeries() {
  this.model = new DataSeriesViewModel();
  this.model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
  this.createComponents();
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  */
 public DataSeries(String label) {
  this.model = new DataSeriesViewModel(label);
  this.model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
  this.createComponents();
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - an array of data points
  */
 public DataSeries(String label, DataPoint[] dataPoints) {
  this.model = new DataSeriesViewModel(label, dataPoints);
  this.model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
  this.createComponents();
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - a collection of data points
  */
 public DataSeries(String label, Collection<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
  this.model = new DataSeriesViewModel(label, dataPoints);
  this.model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
  this.createComponents();
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param model - the model
  */
 public DataSeries(DataSeriesViewModel model) {
  this.model = model;
  this.model.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
  this.createComponents();
 }

 /**
  * creates, binds and configures UI components.
  * data point properties can be created here as components or be painted in paintComponent.
  */
 protected abstract void createComponents();

 @Override
 public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
  this.repaint();
 }

 /**
  * adds a data point to the series
  * @param dataPoint - the data point
  */
 public void addDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {
  this.model.addDataPoint(dataPoint);
 }

 /**
  * returns true if there is a data point with given category
  * @param category - the data point category
  * @return true if there is a data point with given category, otherwise false
  */
 public boolean contains(String category) {
  return this.model.contains(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns the data point with given id or null if not found
  * @param uid - the id of the data point
  * @return the data point or null if there is no such point in the table
  */
 public DataPoint getDataPoint(String category) {
  return this.model.getDataPoint(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns a collection of the data points. the collection supports removal, but does not support adding of data points.
  * @return a collection of data points
  */
 public Collection<DataPoint> getDataPoints() {
  return this.model.getDataPoints();
 }

 /**
  * returns the label for the series
  * @return the label for the series
  */
 public String getLabel() {
  return this.model.getLabel();
 }

 /**
  * sets the max value
  * @param maxValue - the max value
  */
 public Double getMaxValue() {
  return this.model.getMaxValue();
 }

 /**
  * returns the number of data points in the series
  * @return the number of data points
  */
 public int getDataPointCount() {
  return this.model.getSize();
 }

 /**
  * returns an iterator over the data points
  * @return an iterator over the data points
  */
 public Iterator<DataPoint> iterator() {
  return this.model.iterator();
 }

 /**
  * removes all data points from the series
  * @throws PropertyVetoException 
  */
 public void removeAll() {
  this.model.removeAll();
 }

 /**
  * removes the data point with given id from the series, if present
  * @param category - the data point to remove
  */
 public void removeDataPoint(String category) {
  this.model.removeDataPoint(category);
 }

 /**
  * returns the data series view model
  * @return - the data series view model
  */
 public DataSeriesViewModel getViewModel() {
  return this.model;
 }

 /**
  * returns the data series model
  * @return - the data series model
  */
 public DataSeriesModel getModel() {
  return this.model.getBean();
 }
}

    package at.onscreen.chart.builder;

import java.util.Collection;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import at.onscreen.chart.DataPoint;
import at.onscreen.chart.DataSeries;
import at.onscreen.chart.DataSeriesViewModel;

public class BuilderDataSeries extends DataSeries {

 /**
  * default constructor
  */
 public BuilderDataSeries() {
  super();
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  */
 public BuilderDataSeries(String label) {
  super(label);
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - an array of data points
  */
 public BuilderDataSeries(String label, DataPoint[] dataPoints) {
  super(label, dataPoints);
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param label - the series label
  * @param dataPoints - a collection of data points
  */
 public BuilderDataSeries(String label, Collection<DataPoint> dataPoints) {
  super(label, dataPoints);
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param model - the model
  */
 public BuilderDataSeries(DataSeriesViewModel model) {
  super(model);
 }

 @Override
 protected void createComponents() {
  this.setLayout(new MigLayout());
  /***
   * 
   * I want to add a new BuilderDataPoint for each data point in the model.
   * I want the BuilderDataPoints to be synchronized with the model.
   * e.g. when a data point is removed from the model, the BuilderDataPoint shall be removed
   * from the BuilderDataSeries
   * 
   */
 }
}

    package at.onscreen.chart.builder;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import at.onscreen.chart.DataPoint;
import at.onscreen.chart.DataPointModel;
import at.onscreen.chart.DataPointViewModel;
import at.onscreen.chart.ValueFormat;

import com.jgoodies.binding.adapter.BasicComponentFactory;
import com.jgoodies.binding.beans.BeanAdapter;

public class BuilderDataPoint extends DataPoint {

 /**
  * default constructor
  */
 public BuilderDataPoint() {
  super();
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param category - the category
  */
 public BuilderDataPoint(String category) {
  super(category);
 }

 /**
  * constructor
  * @param value - the value
  * @param label - the label
  * @param category - the category
  */
 public BuilderDataPoint(Double value, String label, String category) {
  super(value, label, category);
 }

 /**
  * full constructor
  * @param model - the model
  */
 public BuilderDataPoint(DataPointViewModel model) {
  super(model);
 }

 @Override
 protected void createComponents() {
  BeanAdapter<DataPointModel> beanAdapter = new BeanAdapter<DataPointModel>(this.getModel(), true);
  ValueFormat format = new ValueFormat();
  JFormattedTextField value = BasicComponentFactory.createFormattedTextField(beanAdapter.getValueModel(DataPointModel.PROPERTY_VALUE), format);
  this.add(value, "w 80, growx, wrap");

  JTextField label = BasicComponentFactory.createTextField(beanAdapter.getValueModel(DataPointModel.PROPERTY_LABEL));
  this.add(label, "growx, wrap");

  JTextField category = BasicComponentFactory.createTextField(beanAdapter.getValueModel(DataPointModel.PROPERTY_CATEGORY));
  this.add(category, "growx, wrap");  
 }
}
```

To sum it up: I need to know how to bind a hash map property to JComponent.components property. JGoodies is in my opinion not very well documented, I spent a long time searching through the internet, but I did not find any solution to my problem.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem myself. For anyone who is interested how I did that: I wrote a custom value model for hashmaps (with property change support), then I wrote a custom adapter. The adapter implements ContainerListener and PropertyChangeListener and synchronizes between the model and the view.